# How to overlay a div upon other div while scrolling using css

Tags: jquery, css, html, overlay

I have a webpage header which slides down when a user scrolls down the page.

I am doing this using jquery. It's working but the problem is that the `div` which holds the header is coming behind the other `div`s on the page.

I tried to set its postion to absolute or relative but it didnt work for me.

Here is my code.

***HTML***

```
 <!--End Toolip-->
    </head>


<div id="headerSlideContainer">

    <div id="headerSlideContent">

        Header content goes here!

    </div>

</div>

<!---Myother divs----->
```

***CSS***

```
<style>
#headerSlideContainer {
    position: fixed;

    top:-50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
#headerSlideContent {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

***JQUERY***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var bar = $('#headerSlideContainer');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : '5px'}, 500);
        } else {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 500);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer, because it's unclear.  Could you clarify what you mean by "div which holds the header is coming behind the other divs", please?

Comment: Try setting a higher `z-index` to this div

Comment: FakeRainBrigand sir the main header div is goin behind the other divs

Comment: anu can u please tell me how can i set z-index

Comment: In the css declaration of `headerSlideContainer` add this rule `z-index:10`. This 10 is a random number I chose, you should change it according to the other div on your page

Comment: One more little detail: high value of `z-index` means an high position of the div. So a div with `z-index : 10` will be over a div with `z-index : 5` but under a div with `z-index : 20`. For an "always on top" div use very big value

Comment: Hi.. can u post this in JsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju.. I have done it already.. check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it and I hope this is what you want..

[click this link for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zDEef/)

What I have added z-index wherever needed.. Now this is how css and html looks.

```
<div id="headerSlideContainer">

    <div id="headerSlideContent">

        Header content goes here!

    </div>
    <div id="new">
        Other Contents
    </div>

</div>
```

Css:

```
#headerSlideContainer {
        position: absolute;
         top:0px;
        width: 100%;

       height:1000px;
        background: black;
    }
    #headerSlideContent {
        width: 900px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: white;
        background:Red;
        z-index:10000;
        position:fixed;
    }

    #new{
        top:60px;
        z-index:2;
        height:100px;
        background:Orange;
        position:absolute;
        color: white;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of element that you want to keep at top as fixed.

E.g. if you want to keep #headerSlideContainer at top then

```
#headerSlideContainer{
position: fixed;
}
```

It will do the trick. No need for jQuery.